Maximum integral flow with amplifying edges
How to solve the problem of maximum integral flow with amplifying edges: where one unit of flow becomes w units after passing an edge with amplification value w?
To be precise I want to solve the following problem:

Inputs:

n types of candies, each with a quantity q[i].
m kids, each with:

A satisfaction matrix s[j][i]: the satisfaction a kid j gets per candy of type i.
A satisfaction threshold c[j]: the minimum total satisfaction needed for a kid j to be satisfied.


Special "universal candies" that contribute 1 unit of satisfaction to any kid and are theoretically unlimited.


Objective:

Satisfy every kid's threshold c[j] by distributing candies (and special candies if needed).
Minimize the total number of special candies used.


Constraints:

The total amount of each candy type distributed cannot exceed its quantity q[i].
Each kid can receive any number of candies from each type.


Output:

The distribution of candies.


Input Constraints:

n < 1e2
m < 1e3
q[i] < 1e4
s[j][i] < 1e2
c[j] < 1e5




Example:
Input:
q = [5, 2, 1]
s = [
  [2, 3, 1],
  [1, 2, 3]
]
c = [15, 10]

One possible output could be
[
  [5, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 1]
]

, which costs the least 7 universal candies.
It can be reduced to the flow problem state above with the following input:
([start_node, end_node, capacity, amplification])
[
  [s, q1, 5, 1],
  [s, q2, 2, 1],
  [s, q3, 1, 1],
  [q1, c1, inf, 2],
  [q2, c1, inf, 3],
  [q3, c1, inf, 1],
  [q1, c2, inf, 1],
  [q2, c2, inf, 2],
  [q3, c2, inf, 3],
  [c1, t, 15, 1],
  [c2, t, 10, 1]
]

And the corresponding output is
[
  [s, q1, 5],
  [s, q2, 2],
  [s, q3, 1],
  [q1, c1, 5],
  [q2, c1, 2],
  [q3, c2, 1],
  [c1, t, 15],
  [c2, t, 3],
]

, which has maximum flow of 18.

The input specification does not mention the network with amplifying edges described in your introductory paragraph.  Where does that come from.  Perhaps you could provide a small example of the input along with the expected output - that would make things concrete and give an idea of the input and output format you want to use.

@ravenspoint I've edited the description.

To solve your problem you may use application FF-JW_02-8(shooting from a cannon at sparrows) from 1, that satisfies your Constraints(including Input Constraints) and Objective. you must run the app in variant "By Output Resource" with input data(in text file):
7 13 0 6 200 200
0 1   5  0 1     1
0 2   2  0 1     2
0 3   1  0 1     3
1 4 200  0 2     4
2 4 200  0 3     5
3 4 200  0 1     6
1 5 200  0 1     7
2 5 200  0 2     8
2 5 200  0 3     9
4 6  15  0 1    10
5 6  10  0 1    11
0 4 200  1 1    12
0 5 200  1 1    13

Thanks for your answer but I'm not just looking for a program, not to mention that I have to first create an account in a Russian site. There is a paper mentioned in the site and it's long enough to take me a while to read and see if it's helpful.

This problem can be handled using mixed integer linear programming.
For the problem 2 candies and two kids
q = [1, 1]
s = [
  [15, 15],
  [10, 1]
]
c = [15, 10]

Let fnm be the number of candies type n awarded to kid m
Objective function
maximize f00 * 15 + f10 * 15 + f10 * 10 + f11 

Constraints
f00 + f01 <= 1
f10 + f11 <= 1
f00 * 15 + f10 * 15 <= 15
f01 * 10 + f11 <= 10

The linear programing will set values for all fnm that minimize the total dissatisfaction.  Loop over the kids and top them up with universals until they are satisfies.

For the problem in the original question
q = [5, 2, 1]
s = [
  [2, 3, 1],
  [1, 2, 3]
]
c = [15, 10]

we need
maximize f00*2+f01*3+f02+f10+f11*2+f12*3

constraints
f00+f01+f02 <= 5
f10+f11+f12 <= 2
f20+f21+f22 <= 1
f00*2+f10*3+f20 <= 15
f01+f11*2+f21*3 <= 10


I have added code to automatically generate the objective and constraint functions  https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79267233/blob/df84e3f205b9447169ab6336171f33e7f8f20293/src/main.cpp#L239-L296
output:
Maximize f00 * 2 + f10 * 3 + f20 * 1 + f01 * 1 + f11 * 2 + f21 * 3

f00 + f01 <= 5

f10 + f11 <= 2

f20 + f21 <= 1

f00 * 2 + f10 * 3 + f20 * 1 <= 15

f01 * 1 + f11 * 2 + f21 * 3 <= 10

Here is the code to generate the satisfaction constraints from the input data.
void sProblem::ssex_SatisfyConstraints()
{
    /* There is no need to gave any child more candy
    than will give it the maximum possible satisfaction.

    Sum the product of each candy type anount time the satisfaction per candy
    and limit to the total satisfaction obtainable by each kid
    */

   std::cout << "Satisfaction constraints\n";

    // loop over the kids
    for (int kid = 0; kid < myKids.size(); kid++)
    {
        // construct string to hold the constraint
        std::string ss;

        auto sk = std::to_string(kid);

        // loop over candy types
        for (int candy = 0; candy < myCandy.size(); candy++)
        {
            auto sc = std::to_string(candy);

            // add to sum of previous products
            if (candy != 0)
                ss += " + ";

            // amount of candy to child
            ss += "f" + sc + sk;

            // multiply amount by satisfaction
            ss += " * ";

            // satisfaction per candy
            ss += "s" + sc + sk;

        } // end loop over each candy type

        // maximum satisfaction obtainable
        ss += " <= " + std::to_string(myKids[kid].satisLeft);

        // add constraint to solution explorer
        ssex.constraint(ss);

        // display constraint
        std::cout << ss << "\n";

    }   // end loop over each child
}

I pass the objective function and constrains generated to a solution space explorer ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/SolutionSpaceExplorer ) which gives:
for the three candy example:
Kid 0 gets 4 of candy 0
Kid 1 gets 1 of candy 0
Kid 0 gets 2 of candy 1
Kid 1 gets 0 of candy 1
Kid 0 gets 0 of candy 2
Kid 1 gets 1 of candy 2
kid's satisfaction
14 4
Candy amounts
5 2 1
Total universal 7

For the two candy problem:
Kid 0 gets 0 of candy 0
Kid 1 gets 1 of candy 0
Kid 0 gets 1 of candy 1
Kid 1 gets 0 of candy 1
kid's satifaction
15 10
Candy amounts
1 1
Total universal 0

Complete code for this application at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79267233
Note that the algorithm used by the solution space explorer is adequate for small problems.  Large problems, especially one's with large numbers of candies available of one type, will need to use a "real" ILP algorithm the walks along the edges of the solution space.  Do you have any large problems? If so, please post them to the github repo using the format defined here https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79267233/wiki/Input-file-format  I can then do some performance tests and determine if it would be worthwhile to implement ILP.

I may resort to ILP since that's just magic to me. However, I don't have the constraints like f00 * 15 + f10 * 15 <= 15. I guess it outputs 0 for [1], [[2]], [1] while I want 2 (according to what you maximize.)

All the constraints come directly from the input data.  That one is related to the smaller problem ( 2 kids, 2 candies ).   For your sample problem, f00 * 2 + f10 * 3 + f20 * 1 <= 15 says candy 0 to kid 0 gives 2 satisfaction points per candy and so on for other candies to a maximum of 15.  Do you see?  Please reread the explanation in my answer and look at the code I linked to.  If it still seems impossible, then open an issue on github and we can discuss it there - this space is too cramped for such a discussion

I have added to my answer the code to generate the satisfaction constraints, with detailed documentation.  I hope this will make it clearer where the constraint "comes from".

I meant f00 * 2 + f10 * 3 + f20 * 1 > 15 is possible. For example q=[1], s=[[2]], c=[1]. If you have f00 * 2 <= 1, you got f00 = 0 while f00 should be 1.

I have posted a detailed response at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79267233/issues/2#issuecomment-2541745160 ( There is no room to do so in these teeny tiny comment boxes. )

Special network flow problems can be efficiently solved using some modification of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm
In this case we need to modify the selection of the next augmenting path https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network#Augmenting_paths
Instead of choosing one randomly, or with the greatest flow increase, or the shortest, we should select the path that gives the best improvement of the objective function.
For the 3 candy problem in your question the objective function is
Maximize f_0_0 * 2 + f_1_0 * 3 + f_2_0 * 1 + f_0_1 * 1 + f_1_1 * 2 + f_2_1 * 3
where f_n_m is the amount of candy type n awarded to child m
